# How to show comments notification in php

Tags: php, sql, database

I have three tables "posts", "comments" and "friend_request"

screenshot
[image: Database Structure]

1: If someone comments on SESSION['id'], the notification must appear.

Existing query for "posts"

```sql
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_user = '".$_SESSION['id']."'

post_id = postId;
post_user = postUser;
```

comments on posts

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id = '$post_id' AND user_id != '".$_SESSION['id']."' AND status = '0'"
```

I want if someone comments on my post, and I reply to the comments, I just want to show notifications on the commentator's sidebar only, even if there will more replies.

friend_request is a table where displaying either member are friends or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would approach this is to use a client side AJAX request to a php fetch script that looks at the logged in users `SESSION['id']` to find all comments made by post authors that are children of a comment the logged in user has made

## Frontend

You may use whatever way you want to send a request to your PHP script, I have used jQuery for simplicity.

The jQuery `$.ajax` function will be ran on the page continuously to check for notifications. This has been done by enclosing it in a `setInterval` function.

This code is not tested so not 100% sure on the namespacing of the PHP array you will get back. Best to `console.log` the `data` object in the success handler here.

You will notice that there is reference to a `readComment.php` script, this can be a simple script that sets the `comments.status = 1` to indicate read status.

```
  setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
   url:"fetch.php",
   method:"GET",
   success:function(data)
   {
    console.log(data)
    data.forEach(function(i,v) {
        $( "#notifications" ).append( "<a href=readComment.php?id=" + v.id + ">unread notification</p>" );
    });

   }
  });
 }
}, 60 * 1000); // This will run every minute to check for notifications
```

## Server

`fetch.php`

I am using a select statement here with two `WHERE IN` clauses to retrieve all comments made by post authors that are children of a comment the logged in user has made. I am not 100% on this query either as I have not tested but this should get you started.

```
$query = "SELECT 
    *
FROM
    comments
WHERE
    comments.user_id IN (SELECT posts.post_user FROM posts)
AND
    comments.parent_comment_id IN (SELECT comments.id FROM comments WHERE comments.user_id = ".SESSION['id'].")"
AND 
    comments.status = 0";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

header("Status: 200");
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('data' => mysqli_fetch_array($result) )); 
die;
```

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Thanks for your kind resposne, mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in
/include/nav.php
on line
59

PROVA
 Hey, Demo P
 Home
 News Feed
 Notification
 Inbox
 Email
 Foto
 Drive
 Contacts
 Calender
 Notes
 Takwa
 Business
 Education
 Health
 Heritage
 News
 Library
 Projects

 I'm getting this error?

Comment: Could you try running the query in your database client substituting the `SESSION['id']` for a user who has comments that have a post author replying to them to see if it returns anything? Otherwise I can recreate the schema myself in a few hours and get a working example. Let me know how you go.

i.e: (without indenting because comments won't allow)

`SELECT * FROM comments WHERE comments.user_id IN (SELECT posts.post_user FROM posts) AND comments.parent_comment_id IN (SELECT comments.id FROM comments WHERE comments.user_id = 1)`

Comment: Yes, I used the substituting of SESSION, and already removed extra ( " ) from line 8. And kindly I didn't understand this part of your explanation (readComment.php), do i need to add insert query in readComment.php file?

Comment: The reason why you are getting that error is because the query is not returning anything, this tells me there needs to be more comments that fulfil the requirement you are testing or the query I have written is slightly wrong. I will recreate your database and do some of my own testing.

The `readComment.php` file should include an `$sql = "UPDATE comments SET status = 1 WHERE comments.id = ".$_GET['id']` - this is so that the user can 'dismiss' the notifications.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind resposne, I'll wait for your response, even I've to wait for more than5 hours.

Comment: I have just ran through the `fetch.php` code with the created schema and it seems to be working correctly. Can you show me the output of a `SELECT * from comments` ? Mine looks like this and will work if I pass in user id 2: https://i.imgur.com/QNdNq7e.png   - my posts table: https://i.imgur.com/5FAzAXW.png

Comment: Also, please make sure your `fetch.php` code matches the above - you should not be calling `mysqli_num_rows()` but `mysqli_fetch_array()` on the `$result` from the query. I have ran the above code and can confirm that it's working.